# React: Why does autocomplete unintentionally reset the selected value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, autocomplete

Good evening, i'm trying to solve a problem where the autocomplete value is reset. This happens when i'm changing the state of the UI (example in sandbox). I want the value to still be there, if a user decided to go back and change it. I don't why the autcomplete react that way, but I haven't found a solution.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

**Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-diffie-6ikc6?file=/index.js**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `controlled` version of the autocomplete. The issue is caused by `onInputChange` callback, which fired not just for selecting option. In your case React removes the autocomplete from DOM (because of your `switch`) and it fires `onInputChange` with empty value, so your state changes to empty string.

To avoid this you should use `value` and `onChange` instead. `onChange` fires only if you change the option.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
```

```
<Autocomplete
  value={value}
  disablePortal
  id="combo-box-demo"
  options={movies.sort(
    (a, b) => -b.distributor.localeCompare(a.distributor)
  )}
  onChange={onInputChange}
  groupBy={(option) => option.distributor}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.movie}
  sx={{ width: "100%", paddingRight: 2 }}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff", marginLeft: 25 }}
      {...params}
      label="Movie"
    />
 )}
  selectOnFocus={false}
/>
```

Check it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-shamir-r2dwi?file=/index.js

Comment: Ahh okey that makes sense, was unsure about the onChange / onInputChange difference. However thank you, it works.